__GI__dl_debug_state breakpoints triggers unexpected
Program terminated with signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
#0  __GI__dl_debug_state () at dl-debug.c:74
74      }

The breakpoint here got triggered, however I didn't set any breakpoint here. is this breakpoint auto-set by gdb ? if so why is it auto-set ?
to know what happens.
(gdb) list dl-debug.c:74
64      }
65
66
67      /* This function exists solely to have a breakpoint set on it by the
68         debugger.  The debugger is supposed to find this function's address by
69         examining the r_brk member of struct r_debug, but GDB 4.15 in fact looks
70         for this particular symbol name in the PT_INTERP file.  */
71      void
72      _dl_debug_state (void)
73      {
74      }
75      rtld_hidden_def (_dl_debug_state)


That function is called after the shared library state has been updated, e.g. when new shared libraries are loaded, or existing libraries are unloaded.  GDB stops here and inspects the shared library state to figure out what changed.  However, this should all be handled transparently in the background by GDB, the inferior should see the SIGTRAP from this breakpoint, so something has gone wrong.  Can you share more details, e.g. version of GDB, architecture you're targeting, version of glibc you're using.

In addition to the above, placing a breakpoint on _dl_debug_state is the "old" way of doing things.  Recent glibc/GDB will use tracing probes to perform the same task, but there are separate probes for mapping in, and unmapping, and some other tasks too.  So it would appear that your target is not emitting these probes when the run-time linker is compiled, which might indicate a problem.

@Andrew Hi thanks for the reply, I am trying to debug a heap memory corruption when pthread_cancel is called in a large code base, the way I debug it is I 1st let the memory get allocated and printout the address, the attach a gdb debugger to on of the dummy thread in the process, and add watch point to the process via gdb, however everytime when pthread_cancel is called (even without setting the memory watch point) I hit this trap signal ....
